# Use TFS APIs to process Code Review Request using C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I am using VS 2013 Ultimate. I need to programmatically identify newly submitted Code Review requests, unshelve the associated code and merge it into an existing project in VS, then build and run tests against the resulting code base.
I think the tools I am looking for are in either the WorkItemTracking.Client or VersionControl.Client namespaces; but I am not sure.
Can someone point me to a definitive explanation of the process? Basic samples would be very helpful as it am on a compressed schedule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably best just adding all references from the GAC that have `TeamFoudation` in the name, and let the compiler worry about removing ones you don't use.

Then you you start with [`WorkItemStore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx) class to run your `Query` to get a list of Work Items.

From there you can examine the work items to get the Shelvesets.

Once you know the Shelveset you need to hop onto the [`VersionControlServer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.aspx) to be able to unshelve a Shelveset into a Workspace.

I have some basic TFS API interactions using [Linqpad](http://linqpad.net) on my [blog](http://taeguk.co.uk/blog/my-linqpad-tfs-template/) that I always use as a starting place.

Comment: Thanks Dave! I believe you have supplied the information I need to do what my team has requested.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds an awful lot like a gated checkin to me. For Git-backed projects, TFS 2015 has exactly what you want in the form of [branch policies](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/tfs2015-vs.aspx#gatebld).

For what you're doing right now, I'd just use gated checkin + a [code review required checkin policy](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078).